# Solved: my code is unable to encrypt the password to save in mongoDB after email activation token is decrypted in node js, how can i solve it?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mern, password-hash

i am trying to implement jwt authentication by MERN and in  nodejs i have used an email activation  link to save the user email and password in mongodb. here is my working example for registering the user and activating the user. i am using sendgrid for the email.

```
//for email verification test

signup = async (req, res) => {
  const { username, email, password, passwordCheck, displayName } = req.body;
    //validate
    if (!username || !email || !password || !passwordCheck)
      return res.status(400).json({
        msg: "not all fields have been entered.",
      });
    if (password.length < 8)
      return res.status(400).json({
        msg: "The password needs to be at least 8 characters long.",
      });
    if (password !== passwordCheck)
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ msg: "Enter the same password twice for verification." });
    const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email: email });
    if (existingUser)
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ msg: "An account with this email already exists." });
    const existingUserName = await User.findOne({ username: username });
    if (existingUserName)
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ msg: "An account with this username already exists." });
    if (!displayName) displayName = email;

    const token = jwt.sign(
      { username, email, password, passwordCheck, displayName },
      process.env.JWT_SECRET,{expiresIn:'1000m'}
    );
    const msg = {
      to: email, //receiver's email
      from: "no-reply@test.com", // Change to your verified sender
      subject: `Email verification link ${displayName}`,
      text: "testing from local",
      html: `<h2>Hi ${displayName}</h2> <br/>sends a message for verification test: http://localhost:3000/authentication/activate/${token}</p> <br/><p>Have a nice day</p>`,
    };
    sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_SECRET_API);
    sgMail
      .send(msg)
      .then((result) => {
        res.json({ message: "Email activation link has been sent" });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).json("Error");
      });

}
router.post("/register", signup);

userActivation = (req, res)=>{
    const { token } = req.body;
  if(token){
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET,function(err,decodeToken){
      if(err){
        return res.status(400).json({error:'Incorrect or expired link.'})
      }
    const { username, email, password, passwordCheck, displayName }=decodeToken;
    
    const newUser = new User({
      username,
        email,
      password,
      displayName,
    });
    newUser.save((err,success)=>{
      if(err){
        console.log("Error in signup with account activation",err)
        return res.status(400).json({error:"Error activating account"})
      }
      res.json({
        message:"signup Success!!"
      })
    });
     
  
    } );
  } else{
    return  res.json({error:"Something went wrong"})
  } 

}

router.post("/email-activate",userActivation)
```

while using the postman to save the user with activation key, in mongodb the password is saving in plain text. i don want it to be saved in plain text because of security issue. i want it to be saved in encrypted and tried to use the below code:

```
userActivation = async (req, res) => {
    const { token } = req.body;
    if (token) {
        jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, function (err, decodeToken) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).json({ error: "Incorrect or expired link." });
            }
            const { username, email, password, displayName } = decodeToken;
            console.log(password)
            User.findOne({ email }).exec((err, user) => {
                if (user) {
                    return res.status(400).json({ error: "Username with this email exists." })
                }
                const salt = bcrypt.genSalt();
                bcrypt.hash(password, salt,  (err, passwordHash)=>{
                    const newUser = new User({
                        username,
                        email,
                        password: passwordHash,
                        displayName,
                    });
                     console.log(password) 
                    console.log(passwordHash)
                    newUser.save((err, success) => {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log("Error in signup with account activation", err);
                            return res.status(400).json({ error: "Error activating account" });
                        }
                        res.json({
                            message: "signup Success!!",
                        });
                    })
                })
            })
        })
    }
}
```

when  i start my server and try to sign in with activation key through postman it sends me an activation link. when i try to send the post request through the postman in activation link,postman shows 404 status with "error activating account" and node index shows the following error:

```
        The server has started on port: 5000
    MongoDB connected
    **the real password is showing undecoded**
**the real password is showing undecoded**
    undefined
    Error in signup with account activation Error: user validation failed: password: Path `password` is required.
        at ValidationError.inspect (C:\Myfiles\Reactjs\Projects\test-projects\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\validation.js:47:26) 
        at formatValue (internal/util/inspect.js:731:31)
        at inspect (internal/util/inspect.js:295:10)
        at formatWithOptionsInternal (internal/util/inspect.js:1958:40)
        at formatWithOptions (internal/util/inspect.js:1842:10)
        at Object.value (internal/console/constructor.js:306:14)
        at Object.log (internal/console/constructor.js:341:61)
        at C:\Myfiles\Reactjs\Projects\test-projects\routes\userRouter.js:243:37
        at C:\Myfiles\Reactjs\Projects\test-projects\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4863:16
        at C:\Myfiles\Reactjs\Projects\test-projects\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:16:11
        at C:\Myfiles\Reactjs\Projects\test-projects\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4886:21
        at C:\Myfiles\Reactjs\Projects\test-projects\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:500:16
        at C:\Myfiles\Reactjs\Projects\test-projects\node_modules\kareem\index.js:247:48
        at next (C:\Myfiles\Reactjs\Projects\test-projects\node_modules\kareem\index.js:168:27)
        at next (C:\Myfiles\Reactjs\Projects\test-projects\node_modules\kareem\index.js:170:9)
        at Kareem.execPost (C:\Myfiles\Reactjs\Projects\test-projects\node_modules\kareem\index.js:218:3) {
      errors: {
        password: ValidatorError: Path `password` is required.
            at validate (C:\Myfiles\Reactjs\Projects\test-projects\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1256:13)
            at C:\Myfiles\Reactjs\Projects\test-projects\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1239:7
            at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
            at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (C:\Myfiles\Reactjs\Projects\test-projects\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1184:14)
            at C:\Myfiles\Reactjs\Projects\test-projects\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2502:18
            at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {
          properties: [Object],
          kind: 'required',
          path: 'password',
          value: undefined,
          reason: undefined,
          [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
        }
      },
      _message: 'user validation failed'
    }
```

**According to above try the code is unable to encrypt the password and hence it can't be saved in mongodb. what did i do wrong to encode the password?
so how can i solve it?**

thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const passwordHash =  bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
Here bcrypt.hash returning promise either your can use async/await or use .then().



            userActivation = async (req, res) => {
        const { token } = req.body;
        if (token) {
            jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, function (err, decodeToken) {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(400).json({ error: "Incorrect or expired link." });
                }
                const { username, email, password, displayName } = decodeToken;
                console.log(password);
                User.findOne({ email }).exec((err, user) => {
                    if (user) {
                        return res.status(400).json({ error: "Username with this email exists." })
                    }
//Use genSaltSync when you donot want to use await or your can use await bcrypt.genSalt()
                    const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
                    bcrypt.hash(password, salt,  (err, passwordHash)=>{
                        const newUser = new User({
                            username,
                            email,
                            password: passwordHash,
                            displayName,
                        });
                        newUser.save((err, success) => {
                            if (err) {
                                console.log("Error in signup with account activation", err);
                                return res.status(400).json({ error: "Error activating account" });
                            }
                            res.json({
                                message: "signup Success!!",
                            });
                        })
                    })
                })
            })
        }
    }

Try this code once just put await before bcrypt and made function async.
```

Comment: well it throws the following errors when i run node index:const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
               ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1117:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1165:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1221:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1050:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:938:14)      
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1090:19)
    at require.........

Comment: i have updated the question according to your advice including async/await in such a place where it wouldn't show await related errors

Comment: Please remove await from salt variable it was a mistake updated the answer

Comment: well, i have updated the question where await is in the async function only which in const {token}. salt variable has no longer await. beside i can put await in jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET,function await (err,decodeToken) which has no effect on the error. i just want to save my password as hashed encoding while activation

Comment: Well the error is in password line at its Promise<pending> with await it means that wait until the password is hashed then go to next line I believe the error is only that but can you send the current code of userActivation part in this comment?

Comment: the is huge so i paste it in pastebin: https://pastebin.pl/view/e6903500

Comment: Ok so I have updated the code you can see it in reply just copy and remove from yours. https://pastebin.pl/view/7203dd89

Comment: it is showing the syntax error: const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);   
                             ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1117:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1165:27)

Comment: Ok give me a min

Comment: Sorry cannot test as I am using ts btw here is updated one.
https://pastebin.pl/view/49699403

Comment: well your code obviously made some differences. now i have no errors while running node index. but when i try to use postman by the token activation it is showing the errors but the amount is lesser. i have updated in pastebin with the errors under the code you have given: https://pastebin.pl/view/bf55d22a

Comment: Ok I think password variable is empty I have put log after decode can take from here:
https://pastebin.pl/view/89d1eea7

Comment: thanx for coming back. according to console.log(password), decodeToken is working because it is showing undecoded real password. here the problem is somehow in mongodb passwordHash is not saving and as you have mentioned before it may be not getting enough time to convert it into hash. i think there should be another wy to have this conversion. it's weird why async/await is showing that problem. may be it's just only because of existing in same function. the main thing is my login process is also using the decoding thing.any way, thanx for your try and let me know if you have any more solution

Comment: and i also put console.log(password) and console.log(passwordHash) after bcrypt.hash(password, salt,  (err, passwordHash)=>{
                    const newUser = new User({
                        username,
                        email,
                        password: passwordHash,
                        displayName,
                    }); and the result is it showing the undecoded real password but passwordHash is undefined and after the same errors. so i think it is supporting the same thing that the code is unable to convert the password into hash bcrypt.

Comment: Ok so if its the storage issue then can you share the schema?

Comment: User this const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10); instead of const salt = bcrypt.genSalt();

Comment: well bro, it miraculously solved everything. now will you please update this answer so that i can accept your answer. you deserve this reputations